# Pasar Parametros entre formularios hijos

Tags: c#

tengo este codigo de un aplicacion qu estoy realizando

```
public void AbrirFormulario<MiForm>() where MiForm : Form, new()  {
     Form formulario;
     formulario = PanelContenedor.Controls.OfType<MiForm>().FirstOrDefault();         

     if (formulario == null)
     {
         formulario = new MiForm();
         formulario.TopLevel = false;
         PanelContenedor.Controls.Add(formulario);
         PanelContenedor.Tag = formulario;
         formulario.Show();
         formulario.BringToFront();
     }
     else 
     {
         formulario.BringToFront();
     }  
}
```

para abrir formularios dentro de una panel cuando se abre el
formulario hijo, lo realizo con este codigo:

```
frmLoadMdi frm = (frmLoadMdi)Application.OpenForms["frmLoadMdi"];  
if (Application.OpenForms.OfType<frmLoadMdi>().Any())  {
     frm.AbrirFormulario<frmCompany>();  
}
```

eso desde mi formulario principal.

pero si desde el formulario hijo 1 deso llamar a otro formulario hijo 2, el mismo que debe abrirse en dentro del mimso panel, uso el mismo codigo anterior y funciona correctamente.
el error se presenta cuando quiero pasar un parametro desde el formulario hijo 1 al formulario hijo 2

alguien ha tenido que hacer algo asi

muchas gracias por la ayuda